# Time required for halving of gap

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Variables $x$ changes according to

$$\frac{\dot x}{x} = 0.02 -0.54(\log x(t) - \log x^*)$$

Now we have that $x_1(0) = 2x_2(0)$. Both $x_1$ and $x_2$ change according to the above equation i.e. both change in the same way only the starting point is different. I am asked to find how much time it would take for the gap between $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $10\%$.

I’ve been thinking about it for a while but couldn’t figure out how to approach the question, time isn’t a variable here so how do I solve for it, please help out

Comment: The title doesn't match the question, which asks about reducing the gap to $10\%$ rather than halving it.

Comment: @joriki I was just talking about halving it as an example to see what I’d get when I was using the wrong approach, but I get how to do it now, thanks a lot man!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by “time isn’t a variable here”, as time appears as a variable both explicitly in $x(t)$ and implicitly in $\dot x$.

You want to trace the evolution of $\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)}$. Consider $f(t)=\log\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)}=\log x_1(t)-\log x_2(t)$. Then

$$
\dot f=\frac{\dot x_1}{x_1}-\frac{\dot x_2}{x_2}=0.54(\log x_2-\log x_1)=-0.54f\;.
$$

This is a simple first-order differential equation with solution $f=c\mathrm e^{-0.54t}$, and you can use the given initial condition to find $c$ and then solve for the time at which the final condition is fulfilled.

Comment: I have found that $c = log2$. For finding the time for halving of gap I will solve $\frac{log2}{2} = log2*e^-0.54t$ but this gives $t =.54$ which is not the correct answer so what am I doing wrong

Comment: @user601297: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. To put more than one symbol in the exponent, you need to group the exponent using braces, as in `\mathrm e^{-0.54t}` to produce $\mathrm e^{-0.54t}$.

Comment: @user601297: In the question you wanted the gap to be reduced to $10\%$, so I'm not sure why you're halving it now, but assuming that you want to halve it: $t=0.54$ is not a solution of the equation you wrote, and in any case that equation is wrong. When the gap is half the initial gap, the ratio is $\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)}=\frac32$, so $f(t)=\log\frac32$. Then solving $\log\frac32=\log2\cdot\mathrm e^{-0.54t}$ for $t$ yields $t=-\frac{\log\log\frac32-\log\log2}{0.54}\approx0.993$.

Comment: okay I see so if I were to reduce it to $10\%$ the correct ratio would be $\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)} = \frac{11}{10}$ then $f(t) = \log1.1$ and solving would give $t = \frac{\log\log1.1 - \log\log2}{-0.54} = 1.59$ is this correct now?

Comment: @user601297: There seems to be a notational confusion here – I used $\log$ to denote the natural logarithm (otherwise also denoted by $\ln$); you seem to be interpreting it as the decimal logarithm $\log_{10}$. You want $t=-\frac{\ln\ln\frac{11}{10}-\ln\ln2}{0.54}\approx3.67$. (By the way, you could have noticed that the result is wrong by substituting it into $\log2\cdot\mathrm e^{-0.54t}=\log\frac{11}{10}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the differential equation, switch the variables
$$t'=\frac{50}{x (27 \log (x^*)-27 \log (x)+1)}$$
$$t+C=-\frac{50}{27} \log \left(1-27 \log \left(\frac{x}{x^*}\right)\right)$$ I suppose that you have what you need for solving the problem.